# Find good "targets" for unit tests in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

For a big Project I am now working on, I was going to write some unit Tests.

The problem right now is that I need some kind of aid to determine which methods should be preferred over others, when it comes to unit tests.

Is there a way in Visual Studio (or any other trick) to find interfaces/methods that are used more than others? Any help to find methods that should be targeted via unit tests?

Comment: If you have some method, which executed in five places once a month, then you think it will be more important, then method which is executed every millisecond but called only from one place?

Comment: I'm not sure you should write unit-tests to methold based on their popularity. some code is often used but simple , while other code might be used less but more proned to bugs

Comment: I know this is not a good way to determine methods that should be required to have unit tests but I had to start somewhere. Thats why the title does not read "find heavyly used methods" but the way it is called now :)

Comment: If you're serious about writing unit tests, then your target should be 100% code completion, you write the unit test before writing the code, and as a result any 'preference' becomes irrelevant. That said, if time is limited your order of precedence should probably be based around how important certain features are for the business - and that's not something a tool can tell you.

Comment: @AdrianWragg: Yes I am 100% with you on that and handle it like that when I am writing new code from scratch. However I am now working on a already pretty mature project and was assigned with the task to increase code coverage ("increase" because right now there is almost none ;) )

Comment: @buddybubble Any decent unit test will increase code coverage even slightly, so I personally would go with what is important to the business. You may find that thinking about the business rather than just the code is appreciated by those above you.

Comment: @AdrianWragg Yes you are right and I will do that. However, I was just wondering if there was a tool that shows certain points of interests where mistakes are likely to be made etc

Comment: I think [this][1] might be what you are looking for. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999240/winforms-profile-coverage-find-number-of-times-a-method-has-been-called

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Sorry I think I see what you mean now.

If you right click on a method in Visual Studio and select "Find all references" you can see how many times you call that method.

Comment: Well yes but this is not an option because we are talking about ~ 100.000 lines of code. So I am looking for a tool that helps me a bit in the process and shows points of interest

Comment: Ahh sorry, can't help there. However, going forward, anything new you write you should probably take a TDD route so then you will have 100% code coverage going forward.

Comment: Yes that is how I have been doing it in the past :)